# Change background image and return to the previous view in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I`m making simple game where you can select the background image with this code:

```
-(IBAction)FirstButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture4.jpg"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
    //[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; <-- Not returning to previous view
}
```

I couldn`t figure it out which would be the appropriate code to return the user in the previous view. The uncommented code above is not working, selects the image, but stays in current view. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [self dismissViewController...]

Comment: Its almost working, but I bumped into another problem now. The image is only added to the current view and not the other(there are only two views in the app, and what I wanted to achieve is to place background image in the main view. Any ideas?